# All variables appear to not be POSTing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on a website that takes information from a form in a Bootstrap modal (*addStudentModal.php*) and sends it to *createRecord.php* via a jQuery script (*dataManageFunctions.js*). When the data reaches *createRecord.php*, it gets inserted into a MySQL database. For debugging purposes, instead of executing the INSERT command, I just had it echo out the variables that were POSTed to it. I discovered that all but 2 fields are not getting posted and I have absolutely no idea why. Specifically, *gYear* and *lName* are echoing blank values. I've checked spelling and tried to ensure that the variable names and IDs are identical. Maybe I'm missing something, I don't know.

The files in question are below:

**addStudentModal.php**

```
<!-- ADD STUDENT Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addStudentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add New Student</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="additionResults"></div>
          <!-- EDIT form-->
          <form role="form" action="" method="" id="addStudentForm">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="studentID">Student ID Number:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="studentID" id="studentID" placeholder="123456">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="lastName">Graduation Year:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gradYear" id="gradYear" placeholder="0">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Doe">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="John">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="serHrsToDate">Service Hours to Date:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="serHrsToDate" id="serHrsToDate" placeholder="0.00">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="internToDate">Internships to Date:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="internToDate" id="internToDate" placeholder="0">
              </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="save" value="save"> Add Student </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END ADD STUDENT MODAL -->
```

**dataManageFunctions.js** *- only relevant snippet is copied*

```
// JS for Add Student
$(function() {
  $("#addStudentForm").bind('submit',function() {
    var sID = $('#studentID').val();
    var gYear = $('#gradYear').val();
    var lName = $('#lastName').val();
    var fName = $('#firstName').val();
    var servHrs = $('#serHrsToDate').val();
    var interns = $('#internToDate').val();
     $.post('assetScripts/editInfo/createRecord.php',{sID:sID, gYear:gYear, lName:lName, fName:fName, servHrs:servHrs, interns:interns}, function(data){
       $("#additionResults").html(data);
     });
     return false;
  });
});
```

**createRecord.php**

```
<?php

    include("../../config/db-connect.php");

    $errExist = false;

    if(isset($_POST['sID'])){
        $safeID = intval($_POST['sID']);
        if(!preg_match("/^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*[0-9]).*$/", $safeID)){
            $errExist = true;
        }
    } else {
        $errExist = true;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['gYear'])){
        $safeYear = intval($_POST['gYear']);
        if(!preg_match("/^.*(?=.{4,})(?=.*[0-9]).*$/", $safeYear)){
            $errExist = true;
        }
    } else {
        $errExist = true;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['lName'])){
        $safeLastName = mysql_real_escape_string(filter_var($_POST['lName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    } else {
        $errExist = true;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['fName'])){
        $safeFirstName = mysql_real_escape_string(filter_var($_POST['fName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    } else {
        $errExist = true;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['servHrs'])){
        $safeHrs = floatval($_POST['servHrs']);
    } else {
        $errExist = true;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['interns'])){
        $safeInterns = intval($_POST['interns']);
    } else {
        $errExist = true;
    }

    // check if an error existed when checking inputs
    if(!$errExist){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>Success!</strong></div>';
        echo $_POST['sID'].', '.$_POST['gYear'].', '.$_POST['lName'].', '.$_POST['fName'].', '.$_POST['servHrs'].', '.$_POST['interns'].'<br>';
        echo $safeID.', '.$safeYear.', '.$safeLastName.', '.$safeFirstName.', '.$safeHrs.', '.$safeInterns.'<br>';
        echo $errExist.'<br>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Failure!</strong></div>';
        echo $_POST['sID'].', '.$_POST['gYear'].', '.$_POST['lName'].', '.$_POST['fName'].', '.$_POST['servHrs'].', '.$_POST['interns'].'<br>';
        echo $safeID.', '.$safeYear.', '.$safeLastName.', '.$safeFirstName.', '.$safeHrs.', '.$safeInterns.'<br>';
        echo $errExist.'<br>';
    }
?>
```

It's also worth noting that I also had it echo **isset(*variable name*)** which returned 1 (true) for every variable. And yes, I ensured that the values I entered to test followed every condition so **$errExist** shouldn't have been set true.

Comment: Which variables aren't getting POSTed?

Comment: I just edited my post - realizing that was probably something important. The "gYear" and "lName" are echoing blank values in createRecord.php (That would be gradYear and lastName in the modal)

Comment: Can you check in the network tab of the dev console to see if the data is actually sent to the server?

Comment: Is it possible that you have multiple forms on the same page and another form that contains `id="gradYear"`, etc.? If so, try looking up the the form elements on `this` - e.g. `$(this).find('#gradYear').val()`

Comment: @RobM. Thank you for your answer. $(this) worked.

Comment: That's great @datboi1230, glad to help! :-)